# Erro na função parse_str do php com Carácter especial

Tags: php

Estou tentando usar a função **parse_str** do php colocando como string um valor com o carácter **+**, mas o resultado me retorna a string sem esse carácter, veja:

```
parse_str("c=item1 + item2");
var_dump($c);
```

Answer (score 3):

Esse é o escopo

```
void parse_str ( string $encoded_string [, array &$result ] )
```

Portanto, codifique os caracteres non-ascii antes de passar a função:

```
parse_str(urlencode('c=item1 + item2'));
```

Há outras peculiaridades sobre essa função. Consulte no manual para saber mais: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Comment: Não consegui resolver dessa forma, ele não executa a função se eu codificar a string como você passou

Comment: Consegui resolver codificando somente o valor na string

Answer (score 0):

O caso foi resolvido dessa forma:

```
$str = urlencode('item1 + item2');
parse_str("c={$str}");
```